# Javascript create divs with different ids

Tags: javascript

I want a new div to be created everytime I click on a button. And for that I've been using the following code:

```
function createDiv(){
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id = "div1";
divTag.setAttribute("align","center");
divTag.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
}
```

However this will give every created div the id "div1". I need all the div:s to have different id:s.
It would be nice if every new created div would be named "div + increasing number" (div1, div2, div3, div4, div5) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a counter that is then appended to the ID, then increment the counter.

```
var divCount = 0;
function createDiv(){
   var divTag = document.createElement("div"); 
   divTag.id = "div"+divCount;
   divCount++;
   divTag.setAttribute("align","center");
  divTag.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check if the div already exists and then increase your integer control

```
function createDiv() {
var created = false;
var index = 1;
  while (!created) {
    if (document.getElementById('div'+index) == null) { //not sure if the correct check is like this but something similar will work
      //create div here
      created = true;
    }
    else {
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

Just an alternative

Comment: getElementById lookups are expensive. If you create hundreds of divs, you're basically going to lookup all of those before creating a new one. Cheaper option would be just to remember the the last ID you assigned.